# Is "irresoluteoscillating" a word? Strange result from Thesaurus.com

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, is-it-a-word

I did a [search](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/wavering) on thesaurus.com for the word *wavering*, and one of the suggested synonyms that was listed was *irresoluteoscillating*.

However, the Oxford and Merriam-Webster dictionaries did not have the word listed (Oxford: [link](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=irresoluteoscillating&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch), MW: [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irresoluteoscillating)).

I suspect this is an error on behalf of Thesaurus.com.

Comment: It appears the words "irresolute" and "oscillating" have been concatenated by some kind of code error. You might want to report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, with a space as two words it is a useful phrase for wavering: irresolute oscillating.

Comment: Indeed. I asked because I thought there was a small chance that it could be a strange portmanteau.